# How to read i2c sensor BMP280's data using Yocto poky image OS on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, yocto, i2c, yocto-recipe

I’m new to the Yocto Project. Recently I’ve successfully built the core-image-minimal poky image for Raspberry Pi 3B. But now I want to do read BMP280 I2C sensor data using I2C on Raspberry Pi 3B. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Connections I've made:
VCC pin connects to PIN 17 on the Raspberry Pi board.
GND pin connects to PIN 9 of the Raspberry Pi board.
SCL pin connects to (GPIO3) PIN 5 of the Raspberry Pi board.
SDA pin connects to (GPIO2) PIN 3 of the Raspberry Pi board.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of blogs and wikis about that topic.

***From user-space***

You can use `Python` as following links provides:

Check [this](https://www.iotstarters.com/configuring-bmp280-sensor-with-raspberry-pi/), or [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bmp280-barometric-pressure-plus-temperature-sensor-breakout/circuitpython-test)

***From kernel-space***

You can activate BMP280 driver in the kernel configuration and create a fragment file for it, and then be aware that user-space tutorials will not work as the kernel driver will occupy the I2C bus, so you need then to get data from the driver's attributes files.

```
bitbake linux-raspberrypi -c menuconfig
```

Look for `bmp280` using the `/` button.

Activate the module as `M` or `*`, it is up to you if you want the driver to be included into the Kernel Image or as a separate Kernel module (.ko).

Save configuration and:

```
bitbake linux-raspberrypi -c diffconfig
```

You will get a fragment file `fragment.cfg` :

```
CONFIG_BMP280=m
CONFIG_BMP280_I2C=m
CONFIG_BMP280_SPI=m
```

Get the `fragment.cfg` file path and run:

```
recipetool appendsrcfile -w <path/to/meta-custom> linux-raspberrypi <path/to/fragment.cfg>
```

Rebuild `linux-raspberrypi` and the image as well.

After flashing the new image and connecting BMP280, `insmod`/`modprobe` the driver.

Then, you need to look for the BMP280 driver's sys files and get data from them.

Future idea:

If you are going to make a product that BMP280 will be always plugged in, I recommend changing the device tree file, so you can control the driver's parameters and make sure it is loaded at boot time.

For more detailed information on how to do that check this [link](https://www.blaess.fr/christophe/yocto-lab/sequence-IV-3/index.html) which is talking about adding new hardware via (fragment, devicetree).

It is a french website but you can translate it for very helpful information.

Comment: Using _user space_ approach on Linux kernel with existing driver is almost always a bad idea.